# 'NoSuchKey' code on CloudFront for Angular app

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I created an Angular app and upload it on a bucket S3.
Then I deployed a CloudFront to access my website, but when I want to reach a route of my website (like the /login one) I have the error 'NoSuchKey' :

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
    <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
    <Key>login</Key>
    <RequestId>2F89DD7BB599262C</RequestId>
    <HostId>
        xAEaJF0CRv9Ec9iKtHJ0i+nS8U4nqGCOFHL0vyOEim5MgQiNPqeQNIsxXdTYJdT+MlaYt6l6YJE=
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

Here is my settings for the Bucket S3 :
[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKdiF.png)
AND [Policies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BC3l.png)

And here is my settings for the CloudFront : 
[CloudFront settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dBoS.png)

I understand that this error is due to the fact that '/login' route doesn't exist in my bucket, but I don't understand how can I say to my CloudFront "Use this bucket as website not as bucket or something like this".

Do you guys have any idea of how can I solve this ?

Ask me if any details or more information is needed.

Thanks,
Jb

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to CloudFront -> Error Pages -> Create Custom Error Response

In HTTP error code choose 404. Check the 'Customize Error Response' radio button. In Response Page Path enter your default route (e.g. /index.html). In HTTP Response code choose 200. Wait for CloudFront to update, this can take a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But one question. The day I want to create a personalized 404 error page with Angular, what will happened to this handle error with CloudFront ? I mean, if I enter a false endpoint to my URL, it will redirect me to my personalized 404 page or a loop on index.html ?

Comment: You create the custom 404 page in the Angular router. CloudFront redirects 404 to Angular, Angular tries to match the route, you should then have a default rule that says if the request did not match a route, show your 404 page.

Comment: P.S. The custom 404 page will have a 200 response code. Usually this isn't a problem because your client's browser won't care.

Comment: Ok I understand, thanks a lot for the information and your help !